# WPF vs Windows Store App development

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps

Just really confused:

Is WPF used to develop windows store app? What is the "framework" used to develop windows store app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No WPF is not used to develop Windows Store Apps, both have their own sets of API's.

[WPF sets of API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753307%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Windows Store Apps sets of API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx)

[Difference between WPF & WinRT](http://jesseliberty.com/2013/03/29/windows-8-store-applications-vs-wpf-applications/)